# Is it possible to use Openid for SSO without an email, using a unique id in stead?

Tags: openid-connect

I've been reading up on OpenId,(https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.5.4) and i have a scenario where the "End-User", does not have an email. The question is can a use be authenticated using OpenId without an email address. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a user can be authenticated in any number of ways so long as the OpenID Provider (OP) is capable of doing so. Usually OPs can do this regardless of the presence of an email address - they just need some other form of credential to rely upon.